# Using class as list object in C#

Tags: c#, list, tree

I need to create code that simulate menu in console that has submenus which are also menus:

```
class MenuItem
{
    public int ID;
    public string Caption;
    public List<MenuItem> Children;
}
```

How can I declare Children?

Comment: You already declared it, are you wondering how to initialize it? There are a number of ways to do it.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You have already done what you are asking for!

Comment: Use a TreeView object rather than create your own custom interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `Children = new List<MenuItem>();`

Then if you want to add an item just do:
    Children.Add(new MenuItem ());

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, but :

```
public List<MenuItem> Children = new List<MenuItem>();
```

and you can use

```
myItem.Children.Add(new MenuItem());
```

Comment: You may need a constructor for the class `MenuItem` to initialize the `Childen` propriety with an empty list or you should get ad exception when you try the `.Add`
In C#6 you may use a Property Initializers

Comment: @Matteo - The first part of your sentence is wrong, creating an instance of a  `List<T>` does not require that you can actually create an instance of a `T`.  Also, if no constructor is defined then a public parameterless constructor is inferred so the `Add` call @Vegahyo suggested would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
        Children = new Collection<MenuItem>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public Collection<MenuItem> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var parent = new MenuItem { Caption = "Parent" };
parent.Children.Add(new MenuItem { Caption = "Child1" });
```